BLS API not returning data earlier than January 2022 for CUUR0000SA0 series
I'm using the Bureau of Labor Statistics (BLS) API to retrieve Consumer Price Index (CPI) data for the CUUR0000SA0 series. My goal is to obtain CPI data from April 2020 to April 2024. However, the API response only includes data starting from January 2022, and I'm unable to retrieve data prior to this date.
Here is the code I am using to make the API request:
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

# Constants
CPI_URL = "https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/"
API_KEY = "<<MY API KEY>>"

# Function to get CPI data from the API
def get_cpi_data(start_year, end_year):
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    data = json.dumps({
        "seriesid": ["CUUR0000SA0"],
        "startyear": str(start_year),
        "endyear": str(end_year),
        "registrationkey": API_KEY
    })
    response = requests.post(CPI_URL, headers=headers, data=data)
    response_json = response.json()
    
    # Print the API response for debugging purposes
    print(json.dumps(response_json, indent=4))
    
    return response_json

# Test the function with a range of years
start_year = 2020
end_year = 2024  

try:
    cpi_data = get_cpi_data(start_year, end_year)
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)

The API response includes the following data (truncated here to save space):
{
"status": "REQUEST_SUCCEEDED",
"responseTime": 155,
"message": [],
"Results": {
    "series": [
        {
            "seriesID": "CUUR0000SA0",
            "data": [
                {
                    "year": "2024",
                    "period": "M04",
                    "periodName": "April",
                    "latest": "true",
                    "value": "313.548",
                    "footnotes": [
                        {}
                    ]
                },
                ...
                {
                    "year": "2022",
                    "period": "M01",
                    "periodName": "January",
                    "value": "281.148",
                    "footnotes": [
                        {}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Questions:
Why is the data for months prior to January 2022, including April 2020, not being returned in my API requests?
Are there any specific limitations or additional parameters required in the API request to retrieve the desired data?
Some Sources
The BLS API info is here: https://www.bls.gov/developers/api_signature_v2.htm
And a text file of the series going back many decades (but not available beyond March 2023) is here: https://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cu/cu.data.1.AllItems

On the page you link to it says “Use this signature to retrieve data for more than one timeseries for the past three years”. At best that would be 2021, 2022 and 2023, wouldn’t it? And it likely means 2024 ytd, 2023 and 2022, which is what it returned

Yes - I think I have discovered based on the BLS API documentation and some help from twitter (https://x.com/ernietedeschi/status/1792358211271479510), I modified my approach to loop through years to ensure I get all the data points I need.

Based on the BLS API documentation and help from twitter (https://x.com/ernietedeschi/status/1792358211271479510), I modified my approach to loop through years to ensure I get all the data points I need. Here’s the updated code that works:
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

# Constants
CPI_URL = "https://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v2/timeseries/data/"
API_KEY = ""

# Function to get CPI data for a specific year
def get_cpi_data_for_year(year):
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    data = json.dumps({
        "seriesid": ["CUUR0000SA0"],
        "startyear": str(year),
        "endyear": str(year),
        "registrationkey": API_KEY
    })
    response = requests.post(CPI_URL, headers=headers, data=data)
    response_json = response.json()
    
    # Print the API response for debugging purposes
    print(json.dumps(response_json, indent=4))
    
    return response_json

# Function to get CPI data for a range of years
def get_cpi_data_range(start_year, end_year):
    all_data = []
    for year in range(start_year, end_year + 1):
        response_json = get_cpi_data_for_year(year)
        if response_json['status'] == 'REQUEST_SUCCEEDED':
            series_data = response_json['Results']['series'][0]['data']
            for item in series_data:
                all_data.append({
                    "year": item['year'],
                    "period": item['period'],
                    "value": item['value']
                })
    
    # Convert to DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
    return df

# Get data for the range 2016 to 2024
start_year = 2016
end_year = 2024

try:
    cpi_data_df = get_cpi_data_range(start_year, end_year)
    print(cpi_data_df)
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)

By splitting the queries by year and combining the results, I successfully retrieved data for the entire range from 2016 to 2024. This approach works around the limitation of retrieving multiple years in a single request.
